# How do I pass data from one UIView to a sub UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm having a brain cramp for some reason on this.  Some already posted questions/answers are outdated or objective-C.  I'm not sure if delegate is the way to go?

I have a hierarchy of UIViews.

[image: Pizza String to pass]

In phenotypeSunplotView:UIView some data is set, a string.  I want to pass a string to another class of UIView which actually does the plotting, SunplotView:UIView

For example, I want to pass the string "Gorgonzola" to the class that plots the circle, SunplotView:UIView and plot the string next to the circle.

[image: screendump]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you don't. Views are not data storage objects. They are the "View" in the Model/View/Controller design pattern.

Instead, you set up the view controller to install the data in both places. Give your view controller outlets to all views that it needs to change.

If a view is an input field (like a UITextField for example) then you add an action or delegate method in your view controller that gets called when the user enters data. Then you collect that data and copy it to any other views that are appropriate. The view controller mediates as needed to implement your app's logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I don't want the View to store an object, I just want it to pass it a string and plot it, like a function call.  I guess I'm not getting the concept of "copy it to any other views that are appropriate".

Comment: Think of the view controller as a telephone switchboard. It is the central station that connects to all the views on-screen. From the view controller you can install any values you want in as many views as you want. If you have a value that you need to display in 2 views, just write code that copies that value to 2 outlets. Done.

Comment: Ok but isn't that going to be a bit of a memory hog? leaks? or lots of pointers that could be set to nil?

Comment: In a word, no. What would use more memory? If you're installing values like strings into your views most strings are immutable so a single copy of the same string is shared among your view objects.